# Why is there no middle name field in U.S. visas?

Tags: visas, usa

U.S. visas have Given Name and Surname fields (see [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=U.S.+visa+picture) for examples). The Given Name field might contain just a single name ("John") or multiple names ("John Michael"). But why is there no Middle Name field?

I'm asking because U.S. legal names consist of a first, middle and last name. When a U.S. visa holder with a given name consisting of multiple names ("John Michael") gets a U.S. legal name, it seems to be registered by the Social Security Administration as:

- First name: "John Michael"
- Middle name: none
- Last name: "Smith"

It would seem natural that "Michael" would be registered as the middle name, but the Social Security Administration insists that putting both "John" and "Michael" in the first name is the correct way to construct the U.S. legal name, based on how the name has been entered into the U.S. visa. And they will only register the U.S. legal name exactly as it is in the U.S. visa. But there does not seem to be any Middle Name field in U.S. visas.  Why not?

The result is that foreigners with multiple given names face confusion and frustration when dealing with forms that require entering the U.S. legal name and associated Social Security Number, because most places do not expect the first name to consist of multiple names, while leaving the middle name empty. And it does not seem to be possible to fix this, because U.S. visas do not have a Middle Name field to move the rest of the given names to.

Comment: Why do you think "U.S. legal names consist of a first, middle and last name"?

Comment: My US legal name consists of only first and last name.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not the US government, so we do not know why the US government chose to set out its forms as it does.

Comment: Do you have any evidence to support your assertion that the policy you describe is actually the policy of the SSA? It might in fact simply be the belief of a poorly trained SSA employee.

Comment: Patricia: Because those are the three name components repeatedly asked for. Additionally they are brought up in the Social Security Administration's Program Operations Manual (https://secure.ssa.gov/poms.nsf/lnx/0110205125), for example in the "Identifying first, middle, and last names" section. But if this is not the full story, please enlighten me.

Comment: phoog: Yes, the SSA POMS at https://secure.ssa.gov/poms.nsf/lnx/0110212001 says: "If the applicant has a given name with multiple parts and does not allege having a middle name then the multiple parts should be entered as the first name." Even though the wording "allege having a middle name" opens up the possibility of providing a middle name, how would one support it if the visa does not have a field for Middle Name? The end result is that the SSA just puts all given names in the First Name field.

Comment: @ValkoSipuli I have lived in the US since 1975. "Patricia Shanahan" is my complete legal name. It does not break any of the systems - I have a green card, global entry card, social security card, and California driver's license in that name. I know US citizens with three given names. There does seem to be a preference in some US forms for exactly three names, but that does not mean that a US legal name must conform to that pattern. I am glad to see the visa people getting away from that.

Comment: @ValkoSipuli the visa will be compliant with ICAO standards, which specify a primary and secondary identifier.  The primary identifier under traditional US naming conventions is the last name (i.e., family name) while the secondary comprises the first and middle names (i.e., given names).  All you have to do is say "here are my given names, *John Michael;* my first name is *John* and my middle name is *Michael.*  All you have to do is "allege" that you have a middle name.  You don't have to prove it, and you especially don't have to prove it using any specific document like your visa.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan US visas comply with international (ICAO, to be precise) standards (as do US passports and, I suppose, green cards, which are machine readable).  See http://www.icao.int/publications/pages/publication.aspx?docnum=9303.

Comment: Patricia: You're misunderstanding what I wrote in the question. I'm not saying that all U.S. legal names have a middle name. I was just saying that they are broken down into these three components (first, middle and last). The middle name can be left out/empty if a person does not have one.

Comment: @ValkoSipuli did you notice the part in the page you linked to that said "Whether the middle name or suffix is included, omitted or incorrectly shown on evidentiary documents submitted with an SS-5 (Application for a Social Security number Card) does not matter."  This is after it said "For SSA enumeration purposes, a legal name consists of a
first name and last name (or surname)."  So they've already adopted a definition of *legal name* that is specialized to their purposes and at odds with the practice of pretty much every other institution in the country.

Comment: phoog: Yeah, that is confusing in my opinion. Sounds like the middle name doesn't have any significance under the SSA's definition of a legal name. (Most other places consider the middle name a significant part of a person's full name)

Comment: @ValkoSipuli in fact, not only foreigners but *everyone* with a three-(or-more-)part name will "face confusion and frustration when dealing with" the SSA and their idiosyncratic idea of "legal name."

Comment: phoog: OK, thanks. I basically just want to understand if I have missed something or if it really is like this for every foreigner with multiple given names ("John Michael"). It is counterintuitive that "first name" consists of multiple names – one would expect it to be a single name (it says "first name" and not "first names", after all).

Comment: phoog: Did you mean everyone with _four_ or more parts to their name (including the last name)? Anyone with three parts would just split them up into the expected first, middle and last name, right? Those with four parts need to squeeze two names into either the first or middle name field.

Comment: Just to come back to this, the [ICAO standard for passports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine-readable_passport) used worldwide is to have a surname field and a field for all the given names (first, middle, etc...). Presumably, the State Department sticks with that convention so they can simply take names right off applicants' passports and put them on visas. The Social Security office follows its own conventions, and they've been around a lot longer than the machine-readable passport standard has existed.